# UILabel with basic rich text support

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, richtext

My ipad application has a custom look. It uses text labels extensively for displaying partly colored/shadowed/bold texts. Larger pieces of text may contain numbered lists and embedded Images. There could be couple rich text regions on a single page.

I am not sure that UIWebView is the right tool for displaying strings like:

---

**MyApp** title

---

Hello **rich** *text* world

1. List item
2. List item

---

Writing my own text rendering engine looks more sufficient to me than using UIWebView.
Any ideas for lightweight rich text renderer ? c library or custom control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `TTStyledLabel` from the `Three20` library. It provides the desired functionally and would save you the time of writing your own.

Comment: +1 for correct answer - though Three20 aint that lightweight, it still has plenty of convenient stuff.

Comment: Great ! [TTStyledTextLabel](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_styled_text_label.php) is exactly what I need.

Comment: T20 rocks booth in cricket an in iphone