# how can I set substring of a NSString as bold in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bold & Non-Bold Text In A Single UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel)

I want to know that how can I set substring of a `NSString` as bold in `UILabel` ?

for example : I have a string in `UILabel` say,

```
*Apply to a bill of $16 or more
```

and I want to make " $16 " bold .

Thanks....

Comment: Try to search for "rich text uilabel" for example, there are many similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586871/bold-non-bold-text-in-a-single-uilabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) It's perfect for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could also [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for displaying rich content in iPhone.

[Display Rich Text Using a UIWebView](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/display-rich-text-using-a-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iOS 4 does not support rich text in UILabel yet.

Try some of the answers in this thread: [UILabel with basic rich text support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895306/uilabel-with-basic-rich-text-support)