# Has UILabel rich text support?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Sorry this is a noob question but I am a noob so I hope that is ok.

Say I have a label that displays this:

"I am a Label"

is it possible to make just the word "Label" bold or change its color?

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [UILabel with basic rich text support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895306/uilabel-with-basic-rich-text-support)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UILabel can't support attribute. So you should use the NSAttributedString class.

For example:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"I am a Label"];
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(7,5)];
```

Then draw the AttributedString to the view in the drawRect method.

Comment: oh, found this was ages ago,
now UILabel can support attribute since IOS6 .  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly by using the Apple frameworks and classes. But, you could do this by using the TTAttributedLabel classes. You can find the project at the below mentioned link,
https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: There *is* a way with Apple frameworks: You can use a `CATextLayer` which support `NSAttributedString`, but `TTTAttributedLabel` might be easier to use as it's a view instead of a layer.

Comment: +1 Oops, my bad. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Have a look at [`TTStyledTextLabel`](http://three20.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to split them into two labels.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this with usual lable. Override it, or, if your text is static, use several labels, with diferent text styles. If it's just a background for something, you may put there a picture with this text